# Getting current zoom level in ArcGIS API for JavaScript 4?

Tags: zoom, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

The below code works to get the current zoom level in ArcGIS 3.18 JavaScript API.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
<title>Simple Map</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.18/esri/css/esri.css">
<style>
  html, body, #map {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  body {
    background-color: #FFF;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
  }
</style>
<script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.18/"></script>
<script>
  var map;
  require(["esri/map", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Map) {
    map = new Map("map", {
      basemap: "topo",  //For full list of pre-defined basemaps, navigate to http://arcg.is/1JVo6Wd
      center: [-122.45, 37.75], // longitude, latitude
      zoom: 13
    });
    map.on("extent-change",function(evt)
      {
        console.log("extent change",map.getZoom());
        if(map.getZoom() > 13)
          map.setZoom(13);
      }
    );
  });
</script>
```

But `map.getZoom()` or `map.setZoom()` is not a method in the ArcGIS 4.0 JavaScript API MAP Class.

How do I get the current zoom level in ArcGIS 4.0 map JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with [MapView.zoom](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-MapView.html#zoom) property.